# Displaying Mysql Group_Concat results with Bootstrap

Tags: html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display results from a mysql `GROUP_CONCAT` query using Bootstrap's label html. Currently, if I apply the bootstrap label html to my results I just get one block of items (I guess it's seen as one string) whereas I want them to be in individual blocks See my [bootply fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/mf8sNOeJT2)
Can anyone suggest how I can acheive this?

The Mysql Query

```
SELECT up.file,p.user_name,p.User_email, GROUP_CONCAT(c.collab_username)
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
GROUP BY up.file
```

The html

```
<p class=\"text-left\">Item:".$row['GROUP_CONCAT(c.collab_username)']."</p>
```

http://www.bootply.com/mf8sNOeJT2

Comment: split the results of group_concat by comma (`,`) and store them in an array. And for each of the array value create an item like this `<p class=\"text-left\">Item:".$array[index]."</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode and display

```
$test = explode(',' , $row['GROUP_CONCAT(c.collab_username)']);
foreach($test as $arr) {
    echo '<span class="label label-default">'.$arr.'</span>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I go about also echoing out the other variables from the query also. Would I need to somehow merge another array?